# searching data using sql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a simple sql query where I am trying to allow my employees to have the ability to search for other employees in my db. I want them to be able to search by both, or either first/last name. I have this, but it's not working.

```
 var selectEmployee = "select * from employees where UPPER(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) LIKE UPPER('%" + req.body.search + "%')"
```

so how would I search through both first and last name using the req.body.search value I am passing back?

thanks.

Comment: it should work with first name at least

Comment: it works fine with first name, but last name doesn't work. I want to search both first and last name (since they are two separate columns in my table)

Comment: i believe you want to match either first name or last name

Comment: yes. if someones name is John Doe, I should be able to search either John, or Doe, or both John Doe and have the results still show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OR`

```
var selectEmployee = "select * from employees where FIRSTNAME LIKE '%" + req.body.search + "%' OR LASTNAME LIKE '%" + req.body.search + "%'"
```

you may use UPPER function

Comment: Unfortunately did not work... I tried this, `var selectEmployee = "select * from employees where UPPER(FIRSTNAME) LIKE '%" + req.body.search + "%' OR UPPER(LASTNAME) LIKE '%" + req.body.search + "%'"` and it didn't return any value

Comment: `console.log(selectEmployee)`. Then paste the log into your mysql editor . And share the error, We will find something.

Comment: it worked, I forgot to put before the req.body